# Remove extra top margin for Ant Design Tag

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, antd

I'm using `antd` Tag component, which has `display: inline-block;` property. So it has some extra margin on the top. I would like to remove this extra margin. I've placed the Tag inside a container and added a fix:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  font-size: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  word-spacing: 0;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
`;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Container>
    <Tag>Tag 1</Tag>
    <Tag>Tag 2</Tag>
    <Tag>Tag 3</Tag>
  </Container>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Is there any other way to fix this problem, without adding an extra container for tags?

Here is a link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-tags-extra-margin-h2mh1?file=/index.js:209-264).

This is a screenshot without the fix (there is a margin above tags around 2 px).

[image]

And here is a screenshot with the fix.

[image]

Comment: space as the box is not occupied the full width. try giving font size upper and equal to14px to the tag title.or you need to put padding on top and bottom of the tag button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `vertical-align: top` on each inline-block Tag component to get rid of the extra top spacing.

Also, the height of a [line box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting) is determined by the rules given in the section on line height calculations. I added the necessary CSS for the `.ant-tag` selector if you'd like to vary the line box height on Tag components.

Here is a link to the [fixed CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-tags-extra-margin-forked-o5pfr?file=/index.css)

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to have helped out. If you need more info, [MDN Flow Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Block_and_Inline_Layout_in_Normal_Flow) is a great resource.